# PC hanging and resuming after tick sound

Tags: noise

I'm running a PC with Windows 7 64-bit with the following specs:

```
Intel Core i5 2500K  @ 3.30GHz (35 degrees celcius)
8,00 GB Single-Channel DDR3 @ 668MHz (9-9-9-24)
Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. Z68X-UD4-B3 (Socket 1155) (36 degrees celcius)
1279MB GeForce GTX 570 (EVGA) (36 degrees celcius)
125GB M4-CT128M4SSD2 ATA Device (SATA-SSD)
977GB SAMSUNG SAMSUNG HD103SJ ATA Device (SATA) (24 degrees celcius)
```

I haven't changed any frequencies or voltages. This PC has been running and still runs very well. I have essentially no problems with it, but there's one small thing.

I'm working on the computer and I try to perform a certain action. It could be anything from opening a menu from a taskbar icon or executing a download in Chrome.

Sometimes (once a week or so) simply nothing happens, as if the program is ignoring my action. Then I wait a few seconds and this tick noise comes from my PC case and the program suddenly responds to my input. It's as if it takes time to wakes up. Note that the rest of the PC is still responsive during this time, it's no complete PC freeze.

Does anyone know from what component this noise could be coming from? I'm thinking that there is only one component that could physically make any sudden noise at all and that is the hard drive. Could it be faulty?

Comment: Clciks are baaaaad. Backup your data just in case, the hard drive is a likely culprit.

Comment: Your HDD is about to fail.  Check the Reallocation S.M.A.R.T data on the hdd.

Comment: I just ran a SpeedFan test and it resulted in no errors. Reallocation value is 252. See data here: http://i.imgur.com/dJpZ86f.png I watched a video of the clicking of death and it's nothing like that.